# Where to start in Linux programming

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am a student and I would like to study all these terminal stuffs and all. You all will be experts in this subject. I would like to know where did you all begin and what must I do to be an expert in linux programming or the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to know all the commands that you can use in terminal, then you can use this book *Linux Complete Command Reference*  I got it about 2 weeks ago, ans I think its excellent.

And as far as programming goes, you might want to take a look at [This](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Can you specify the author of the book Linux complete command reference

Comment: The book was compiled by J. Purcell.  and the International Standard Book Number: 0-672-31104-6

Answer (score 1):

When I first got started I used this :

http://linuxcommand.org/index.php

Download the book, free. The site is just chapters from the book.

Also Bash Reference Manual @ http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html