# Moving like named files into self-named directories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files, directory

I have several thousand files in one directory that I would like to collate in directories like so:

From this:

```
└── Files
    ├── AAA.mkv
    ├── AAA.nfo
    ├── AAA-picture.jpg
    ├── BBB.mp4
    ├── BBB.srt
    ├── BBB-clip.mp4
    ├── CCC.avi
    ├── CCC.srt
    ├── CCC-clip.mov
    └── CCC.nfo
```

To this:

```
└── Files
    ├── AAA
    │   ├── AAA.mkv
    │   ├── AAA.nfo
    │   └── AAA-picture.jpg
    ├── BBB
    │   ├── BBB.mp4
    │   ├── BBB.srt
    │   └── BBB-clip.mp4
    └── CCC
         ├── CCC.avi
         ├── CCC.srt
         ├── CCC-clip.mov
         └── CCC.nfo
```

The file names vary in length and number of words, sometimes separated by spaces and possibly a few with hyphens (in addition to the ones ending '-short'.  They are primarily video files with a variety of formats/containers: mov/mpg/mkv/mp4/avi/ogg.  Some are subtitled.  Some have files with associated metadata (.nfo or -clip)

Edit: The primary files are videos (this is where I would like to draw the directory name). The associated files represent metadata. Some different in naming by only the extension. There are a half-dozen other variations on the base filename like -clip.mp4 -clip.mov or -picture.jpg  I figured if something were suggested with those few then I could (hopefully) work at figuring out the rest. In summary, AAA.mkv moves into a directory called AAA.  Then all metadata files that begin with AAA join it (i.e., in this example: AAA-picture.jpg and AAA.nfo). So the basename is in fact a substring in the case of the AAA-picture.jpg file.  I would say it is probably relatively safe to simply use the hyphen as the delimiting factor... though '-clip' or '-picture' in its entirety would be safer.

How can I do this without getting carpal tunnel syndrome?
I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302668/move-multiple-files-to-multiple-folders-based-on-names-of-files) but it was sufficiently different that my weak scripting abilities fizzled.

Thank you.

Comment: So, from your example, it looks like you actually want to make directories that *start* with some string, instead of make directory for each file name. So then, how do you want a script to handle stuff like `AAA-picture.jpg`  ? What's supposed to be the "rule" which determines how to create folder ?  How much of the filename is supposed to be extracted ? Of course, we can split filenames using `.` and `-` as separators and extract first part.  But you also say they can be separated by spaces and other characters,so then question do they follow same rule , `AAA` then separator then other text ?

Comment: @Serg I think he simply wants a subdir for each (base) filename.

Comment: @JacobVlijm look at the second example. If this was simple basename extraction, he'd have directory for basename `AAA` and `AAA-picture`. In this case, however, he wants both `AAA.mkv` and `AAA-picture.jpg` to be under `AAA` folder. This is not basename extraction, it's substring extraction, or at least splitting filename at multiple separators and using first string as directory name.

Comment: You are right! I missed that. I think however it is a typo, looking at the second folder.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  typos don't happen 3 times :)  Same thing with `BBB-clip.mp4` and `CCC-clip.mov`

Comment: @Serg let's see what he sais :) removed it for now.

Comment: Have posted an edit to clarify: man you people are blazingly fast with responses!

Comment: @MrFinn Ah, I see. *if* using a hyphen is usable, the script should do it :). Please test on a sample first!

Comment: Very well, the edit seems to confirm my guess. I'll see what I can make

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your question is tagged with `bash`, this would be somewhat troublesome ( in my humble opinion ) to use `bash` for such task. I'd suggest using python because it has a lot of good functions for complex tasks and this answer provides a solution using that language.

Essentially what occurs here is that we use regex to split filenames at multiple delimiters, get only first part and use unique set of those first parts as basenames for new directories.

We then traverse the top directory again , and sort the files in their appropriate places.

The script doesn't do anything spectacular, and actually in algorithm analysis this wouldn't do too well, because of the nested for loops, but for "quick and dirty, yet workable" solution it's alright. If you are interested what each line does, there's plenty of comments added to explain the functionality

**Note**, the demo only shows printing of the new filenames for testing purpose only. Uncomment the `os.rename()` part to actually move the file.

#### The Demo

```
bash-4.3$ # Same directory structure as in OP example
bash-4.3$ ls TESTDIR
bash-4.3$ # now run script
AAA  AAA.mkv  AAA.nfo  AAA-picture.jpg  BBB  BBB-clip.mp4  BBB.mp4  BBB.srt
bash-4.3$ ./collate_files.py ./TESTDIR
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/AAA/AAA-picture.jpg
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/AAA/AAA.mkv
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/AAA/AAA.nfo
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/BBB/BBB.srt
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/BBB/BBB.mp4
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/BBB/BBB-clip.mp4
```

#### Script itself

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re,sys,os

top_dir = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])

# Create list of items in directory first
# splitting names at multiple separators
dir_list = [os.path.join(top_dir,re.split("[.-]",f)[0])
            for f in os.listdir(top_dir)
]
# Creating set ensures we will have unique
# directory namings
dir_set = set(dir_list)

# Make these directories first
for dir in dir_set:
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)

# now get all files only, no directories
files_list = [f for f in os.listdir(top_dir)
              if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(top_dir,f))
]

# Traverse lists of directories and files,
# check if a filename starts with directory
# that we're testing now, and if it does - move
# the file to that directory
for dir in dir_set:
    id_string = os.path.basename(dir)
    for f in files_list:
        filename = os.path.basename(f)
        if filename.startswith(id_string):
           new_path = os.path.join(dir,filename)
           print(new_path)
           #os.rename(f,new_path)
```

#### Additional notes:

- The script can well be adapted to split files at other multiple separators (in the `re.split()` function): add inside square brackets ( meaning `"[.-]"`) add whatever characters you want.
- The moving part is performed with `os.rename()` function. Alternatively you could `import shutil` and use `shutil.move()` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858026/3701431

Comment: I replaced os.mkdir(full_path) with os.mkdir(dir) and that seemed to work and that seems to work.  Then I redid the commenting and (as in the link you provided) supplied the full path name to os.rename by changing it to os.rename("/full/path/to/files/"+f,new_path).  This worked on my test directory.  Now I just have to work up the guts to apply it bulk to my full directory.

Comment: @MrFinn oops, thank you for spotting the epic error. That's what happens when I write scripts on sleep deprived head. I'll edit it once I'm on my laptop again.

Comment: I appreciate your work. I replaced my hardcoded path with os.path.abspath(top_dir)+"/"+f ... which is probably still not as elegant as it could be but it seems to work.

Answer (score 9):

I made a small bash script to do this, simplified and improved thanks to comments from OP, @dannysauer, @Arronical and @Scott

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
  do mkdir -p "${file%%[.-]*}" 2>/dev/null
    if [[ -d "${file%%[.-]*}" ]]; then
       if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
         echo mv -v -- "$file" "${file%%[.-]*}"
       fi
    fi
done
```

Run with `echo` first and then remove `echo` to actually move the files. The script must be run from the directory where you want to move the files. If you prefer, here it is as a one-line command:

```
for file in *; do mkdir -p "${file%%[.-]*}"; if [[ -d "${file%%[.-]*}" ]]; then if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then echo mv -v -- "$file" "${file%%[.-]*}"; fi ; fi ; done
```

(again, remove `echo` after testing)

#### Explanation:

- `for file in *; do mkdir -p "${file%%[.-]*}"` make a directory with the name of the first part of the name of each file (until the first hyphen or dot character) The `-p` flag is very important here - without it, the script will move only the first matching file (thanks to Arronical for [pointing out that `-p` will stop `mkdir` from trying to create existing directories and complaining about it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849215/moving-like-named-files-into-self-named-directories/849236?noredirect=1#comment1304238_849236))
- `2>/dev/null` the script complains that it cannot create a directory with the same name as itself (but still works) so we throw away the error - this isn't needed when running as a one-liner
- `if [[ -d "${file%%[.-]*}" ]]; then` if there is a directory with that name (if the `mkdir` was successful) then...
- `if [[ -f "$file" ]]` if we are dealing with a file (not a directory or something else) then...
- `mv -v -- "$file" "${file%%[.-]*}"` move it into the matching directory.

Comment: To avoid creating directory for script itself, one could also turn this into a `~/.bashrc` function ;)

Comment: You can use `mkdir -p` which doesn't complain about directories already existing.

Comment: Some of the filenames have spaces and/or underscores. After a bit of regex googling, I replaced [:alnum:] with [a-zA-Z0-9\ _] but then it seems to pick up the extension (includes the period?) and I find myself at a loss (since it can't create a directory with the same name as the file).

Comment: (1) To avoid creating a directory for the script itself (and moving the script there), put the script in a different directory, or give it a name beginning with **`.`**.  (2) Line 7 of the script refers to `filenames`, which, at that point, is equal to the (lexicographically) last filename in the directory.  Do you mean to refer to `files`?  (3) At line 6, why not just say `for files in "$dirs".* "$dirs"-*`?  (4) As a matter of style, I prefer to say `for dir in …` and `for file in …`; i.e., use *singular* words for the loop index variable (which takes on only one value at a time).

Comment: Use `${filename%.*}` instead to prune everything after the last period. Then the filename contents don't matter and got can avoid the complexity.  You could also do it in one much shorter loop over the files by doing the mkdir and then the mv.

Comment: I'm thinking something like `mkdir -p "${f%.*}" && mv -v "$f" "${f%.*}"`. Which is a huge pain to type on a phone keyboard. :)

Comment: @dannysauer :) yeah this works  `for f in *; do mkdir -p "${f%-*}" && mv -v "$f" "${f%-*}"; done` (tested on my phone, on Termux) although for OP separator could be hyphen or dot... It didn't work for me before because I wasn't using `-p` (without that it only moves the first file). Maybe I'll simplify my answer (it will be nice not to parse `find` output) when not at phone keyboard myself.

Comment: Whoops; I missed the hyphens.  If one can guarantee that the files don't contain hyphens or periods, one could use `${f%%[.-]*}` instead, thus pruning the longest match after either one.  I like `d=${f%.*}; d=${d%%-*}` a bit better, though that's probably overkill.

Comment: @dannysauer *facepalm* why didn't I think of `[-.]`?

Comment: It's the shell; the default mode for brains when using a shell is to think of simple globs rather than regexps. ;)

Comment: @MrFinn I think I fixed it now, it turned out to be really simple!! thanks to dannysauer. I can't believe I forgot I could use a character class for hyphen or dot

Comment: @dannysauer haha so true, I'm thinking "DON'T try to use regex in the shell" but really, no excuse for not thinking of a char class. I've edited, and the first test is probably overkill (and maybe useless) but I'm very happy that it works better and doesn't parse `find`. I owe you a drink :)

Answer (score 5):

On a small python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    split = f.rfind("."); short = f.find("-")
    if split != -1:
        extension = f[split:]
        newname = f[:short] if short != -1 else f[:split]
        target = os.path.join(dr, newname)
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            os.mkdir(target)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(dr, f), os.path.join(target, f))
```

To use it:

- copy it into an empty file
- Save it as `move_into.py`
- Run it with the directory as argument:

  ```
    python3 /path/to/move_into.py /path/to/directory
  ```

The script assumes all (relevant) files have extensions. If a file has no extension, nothing happens with it. If that is an issue, please mention, can be changed easily.

#### Explanation

- The script looks for possible extension.
- If not present, the script leaves the file (or dir) alone.
- Else the file will be split by "-", if present, the first section is subsequently used to create folders (if necessary)
- If not, the basename of the file is used to name the folder.

Subsequently, the file is moved into the corresponding folder.

Comment: @Serg that is why I used rfind, to only find the last dot, splitting off the extension.

Comment: @Serg edited my answer.